# Is there a way to find which all GCS buckets are currently active in a given project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a GCP project say A where I have 1000's of buckets created as a result of bad practices by users/applications which may or may not exist anymore. All the buckets have objects/data inside ranging from few MB to TB, but we are not sure if that data is relevant or that is ever accessed by any user or application.
Is there a way to find out which all buckets are active for say last 6 months or 1 year ? by active I mean any activity has been performed on it for e.g. a read or a write.

Thanks again for looking into it.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have logs enabled for Cloud Storage? If yes, check them.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, but that won't help for 1. Entries are also generated in Log when there is a list operation done on bucket or someone clicked on it - that doesn't mean an object was accessed. and 2. It's not ideal to scan through log entries for thousand of buckets. Correct me if I'm missing anything ?

Comment: Reviewing the logs is your **only** option.

Comment: Can't monitoring be of any help ?

Comment: Reviewing the logs is your only option.